Using Schwiftly and Pandas - TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'Series'
i have a csv (semicolon separated, text qualifier ") which contains business partners with their data (address, bank account etc). This data, esp. the IBAN, needs to be validated. For the IBAN I use Schwifty:
import pandas as pd
from schwifty import IBAN

importfile = 'bp.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(importfile, sep=';', encoding='latin-1')
df['IBAN_remarks'] = IBAN(df['IBAN']) 

But there is a error: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'Series'
type conversion to string with df['IBAN_remarks'] = IBAN(str(df['IBAN'])) is not working as intended: All IBANs are concatenated.

raise exceptions.InvalidStructure(f"Invalid characters in IBAN {self!s}")
schwifty.exceptions.InvalidStructure: Invalid characters in IBAN 0DE625001051753153984831DE625001051753153984832DE625001051753153984833DE625001051753153984834DE625001051753153984835NAN6DE625001051753153984837DE625001051753153984838DE625001051753153984839DE62500105175315398483NAME:IBAN,LENGTH:176,DTYPE:OBJECT*

What am I doing wrong?
Best regards,
Robert
Type conversion. I want to add a validation text for each IBAN.

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object, got 'Series':  It's telling that you need to pass a string or bytes-like object as an argument, but you pass a series (df[‘IBAN’]). Let's take a simple list example to illustrate.
If we have a list a = [‘1’, ‘2’], then a is a list with strings as elements, not a string. (df[‘IBAN’]) is series, not string.

The cause of the error is explained above, and the solution is following: if you want to apply the IBAN function to each cell in the series, use apply. Study the link and try it out.

apply the func to each IBAN instad of applying it ot the serie:
df['IBAN_remarks'] = df['IBAN'].apply(IBAN, axis=1) 

